# Remove empty value from lists which are in a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dict where the values are a list of strings. Some values in this list are empty (like empty string). Now I need the dict with all the keys as original but want to remove the empty values from the list. Could someone please help as I think it can be done using filter() for lists in python. Below is an example of the original and final dict required

```
original_dict = {"abc": ["","red","green","blue"], "def":["amber","silver","","gold","black","",""]}
output_dict = {"abc": ["red","green","blue"], "def":["amber","silver","gold","black"]}
```

Comment: Might not be relevant here, but if you are creating this dict, a better question could be how to avoid those empty strings in the first place...

Comment: I checked the above related question, and it does not answer the query that I had. The above link only mentions about lists and not lists in a dict.

Comment: What you want is to change lists. They just happen to be values in a dict. Modifying values in a dict is a simple task surely answered here as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested comprehensions will let you make a new `dict`:

```
original_dict = {"abc": ["","red","green","blue"], "def":["amber","silver","","gold","black","",""]}
output_dict = {k: [x for x in v if x] for k, v in original_dict.items()}
```

If you want to modify the original `dict` and its `list`s in place (so aliases see *all* changes, whether they alias the `dict` or the contained `list`s), you can avoid touching the keys and just replace the contents of each `list` with the pruned version, like so:

```
for v in original_dict.values():
     v[:] = [x for x in v if x]  # Or v[:] = filter(None, v) if you prefer
```

The `[:]` in there is what makes even aliases of the `list`s get changed. If you didn't want to change them in-place, you'd need the keys (to enable reassignment) and you'd instead do:

```
for k, v in original_dict.items():
     original_dict[k] = [x for x in v if x]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for k,v in original_dict.items():
    original_dict[k] = list(filter(None, v))
```